# java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target with Cobertura using mojo

Tags: java, junit, cobertura, mojo

I am using Cobertura for my code coverage but while running the test cases all of the test cases are getting failed with below error when I run the test cases using a maven build.

```
 Reason:
    Expected stackmap frame at this location.
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 033d 11ff ff3e 125b 1102 1fb8 0061 2a2b
    0x0000010: 1102 1f3d 1100 003e c600 1912 5b1c 1d04
    0x0000020: b800 b511 ffff 3e2b b600 bbc0 00b7 a700
    0x0000030: 141d 9b00 0f12 5b1c 1d03 b800 b511 ffff
    0x0000040: 3e01 b500 c012 5b11 0220 b800 61b1
```

But when I run the same test cases using Eclipse run as JUnit command it works fine.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to simply disable bytecode verification - see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300639/use-of-noverify-when-launching-java-apps

Comment: @GhostCat tried that but it didn't work<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <argLine>-noverify</argLine>

Comment: Then I suggest: carefully carefully study what eclipse is doing differently when invoking JUnit. Which libraries, which JVM settings, whatever.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse just Right Click & in in cover configurations & add 
`-XX:-UseSplitVerifier` to the VM Arguments in the arguments tab

Comment: Is there a way I can put this in Gradle so my team can use ?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, using *AdoptJDK 11*, I was able to get rid of the error using the `-noverify` VM argument. However, Cobertura doesn't support Java 1 :(

For Gradle users:

```
test {
    jvmArgs '-noverify'
}
```